# How to get the rank of a specific user with MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

[image]

I'm going to calculate and get the rank of **all users** and **a specific user** with **no duplicate** rank in the list. The rank has to be based on this:

```
order by progress_percent desc, gold_count desc
```

Suggest a query to achieve such a thing.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: 6.3.6 is the version of MySQL Workbench, not of the database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Beat me to it. To get the version of the database, you can use your MySQL Workbench to inspect your server under Server Status. Or you can run a query for `SELECT @@version;` OR `SELECT version()`.

Comment: @Shawn '10.1.34-MariaDB'

Comment: You say you want no duplicate ranks, but how do you intend to handle ties?

Comment: @Shawn what if we check `modify_date` too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will be glad for the day when MySQL 5x is fully supplanted by MySQL8+ and there are for real Window Functions in MySQL. Until that day, though, for MySQL 5x / MariaDB <10.2, you can use something like:

```
SELECT username
  , progress_percent
  , gold_count
  , @uRank := @uRank + 1 AS theRank
FROM mytable t, ( SELECT @uRank := 0 ) r
ORDER BY progress_percent DESC, gold_count DESC, modify_date DESC
```

*EDIT: Apparently Window Functions weren't added to MariaDB until 10.2. :-S*

If you were using MySQL 8+ or MariaDB 10.2+, you could just use a Rank Window Function:

```
SELECT username
  , progress_percent
  , gold_count
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY progress_percent DESC, gold_count DESC, modify_date DESC ) AS theRank
FROM mytable t
ORDER BY theRank
```

**EDIT 2:**

For a specific user, just put the above queries into a subquery and `SELECT` the `Rank` you want.

```
SELECT s1.username, s1.progress_percent, s1.gold_count
FROM (
    [above query here]
) s1
WHERE s1.theRank = <theRankYouWant>
```

or

```
WHERE s1.username = <theUsernameYouWant>
```

Comment: What if I want rank for a specific user (for the first approach)?

Comment: You need to wrap it in a other query like so  `SELECT * FROM ( one_off_the_qeuries ) alias WHERE username = <username>` @MasoudDarvishian

Comment: @MasoudDarvishian Modified answer.

Comment: You need to use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead off the `RANK()` window function within the MySQL 8.0+ query.. Because `RANK()` will number ties the same `ROW_NUMBER()` does not do this.. Using `ROW_NUMBER()` matches the implementation with the MySQL's user variable which also does not number ties the same.

Comment: @RaymondNijland You're correct. Wasn't thinking. Answer updated.